# Is there a name for an answer to a question that does nothing but rephrase the question in an answer form?

Tags: single-word-requests

*(if you can think of a better title please change it, I know it's bad)*

Is there a name for an answer to a question that does nothing but rephrase the question in an answer form? For example, if you were asked something that you didn't know the answer to and were trying to be funny / intentionally not helpful.

Examples:

> Q: What is a dog house?
>   A: It's a house for dogs.
>   Q: What is the typeDefinitionAccessCode variable used for?
>   A: It's used to store the access code of the type definition.

Comment: I would call it "an answer to a question that does nothing but rephrase the question in an answer form".

Comment: @MarkBeadles Delightfully witty of you, sir!

Comment: You sir are a delightful character

Comment: @MarkBeadles: You beat me to it!

Comment: It is not obvious that the examples given really 'rephrase the question'. There is no question left when one is told 'It's a house for dogs'; it is a perfectly good answer. The answer is not only accurate, but also informative: it tells us that *dog house* is not a metaphor, or a peculiar idiom, or a technical term. A learner of English who had just been struggling with the meaning of *hot dog*, would find that answer very helpful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you might be looking for *[tautology](https://legacy.theskepticsguide.org/resources/logical-fallacies)*:

> [Tautology] is an argument that utilizes circular reasoning, which means that the conclusion is also its own premise. Typically the premise is simply restated in the conclusion, without adding additional information or clarification.

This citation is from The Skeptic's Guide to the Universe.

Comment: There's a [club](http://xkcd.com/703/) for that

Comment: @Jim: Excellent [trouvaille](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=trouvaille&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=vDhpT6-dDIfR8gOX44yaCQ&ved=0CCcQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=83e001d13871f6c4&biw=1290&bih=902)!

Comment: Who is being quoted here? This doesn't match definitions of "tautology" I've seen, though it does _contain_ an actual tautology: "adding additional" ("adding" would have been sufficient - it's already clear the information is additional if it's being added).

Comment: @spume I updated the link and added attribution. Wikipedia has some examples of [tautology (language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(language)) that illustrate my conclusion that this is a good word for OP's situation. It boils down to "A dog house is a house for a dog", which is similar to "After we change the game it won't remain the same."

Answer (score 5):

*Begging the question* —  [An excerpt from this link:](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/begquestionterm.htm)

"Begging the question is also known as circular argument, tautology, and petitio principii."

"Here is an example [of begging the question] taken from an article on exclusive men's clubs in San Francisco. In explaining why these clubs have such long waiting lists, Paul B. 'Red' Fay, Jr. (on the roster of three of the clubs) said, 'The reason there's such a big demand is because everyone wants to get in them.' In other words, there is a big demand because there is a big demand."

(H. Kahane and N. Cavender, Logic and Contemporary Rhetoric: The Use of Reason in Everyday Life, 10th ed. Wadsworth, 2006)

Comment: I think begging the question is a slightly different form of circular reasoning than a tautology. A tautology is literally restating the premise in different words; begging the question is used when trying to *prove* something that may or may not be true by assuming it is true. Saying "club X is in demand because lots of people want to get in." would be a tautology if it was accepted as true that club X was popular, and begging the question if club X's popularity were up for debate. (In particular, tautologies are logically valid, begging the question is a fallacy.)

Answer (score 2):

I would call it *circular inquiry*.

Comment: I've heard of *circular logic* or *circular reasoning* but not a circular inquiry. Could you cite a source, or provide an example sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I would call it an instance of a "useless" reply. The restatement that you mention is just a special case - the most obvious case - of uselessness. Other useless answers - sometimes offered as jokes or witticisms - take a microsecond longer or so before their uselessness is perceived, and so have some significant impact (i.e., the double-take factor applies). For example:

A. "What is the secret to getting rich in the stock market?"

B. "Buy low; sell high".

Or again, Mark Twain's "I was gratified to be able to answer immediately: I said I didn't know."

Or again, Al Capone's answer to the prosecutor: "To the best of my recollection, I can't remember."

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it *shallow* as in a *shallow answer*.

Comment: But sometimes it's all the answer that is needed.

Comment: You are right, fact that turns my answer into basically, crap.

Answer (score 1):

I might call it a *smart answer*, especially if it seems designed to be sarcastically funny or unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a "meta answer." I learned the usage of the word, 'meta' meaning self-referencing from the answers to my question, "What does 'It's sorta meta' mean?" that I posted in this forum a half year ago.